# RSpec - Check sessions with Basic Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec

I'm trying to check if my sessions works well with basic authentication. Here is my controller :

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :authenticate

  def create
    @client = Client.create!({
      :user_id => @current_user.id
    })
    session[:client_id] = @client.id
    render(:xml => { :status => 'OK' })
  end

 private

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      # User checking...
      @current_user = checked_user
    end
  end
end
```

end

It's a very basic controller. But when I try to see if `session[:client_id]` is correctly set, it's just returning `nil`.

I didn't write the initialization of `@user`.

```
it "should create session" do
  request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(@user.login, @password)
  post :create
  response.should be_success # not fail
  Hash.from_xml(response.body)['hash']['status'].should == 'OK' # not fail
  Client.last.user.should == @user # not fail
  assigns(session[:client_id]).should == Client.last.id # Fail !
end
```

The error is that `assigns(session[:client_id])` is `nil`... I'm totally sure the `@client` is initialized and the render is OK, but session seems not to be saved.

It's the first time I use rspec with session. Is it the correct writing of this test ?

Regards

Comment: You can call `session[:client_id]` in your tests as normal. No need to pass to assigns.

Comment: OK. It works... but very confusing usage of session keyword for assign and get...

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is the line:

```
assigns(session[:client_id]).should == Client.last.id # Fail !
```

`assigns` is a method that is going to point to the equivalent instance method, so `assigns(session[:client_id])` is going to check for `@session[:client_id]`, which it won't find.

Also, the session hash is available in rspec so you can call it like you would in your controller, which is what you need to do here:

```
session[:client_id].should == Client.last.id # pass
```